# Detect changes on json file in Ansible: jq uses different indention -> File is always changed

Tags: json, ansible, jq

Using Ansible, I want to replace a string in a json file. It seems Ansible has no similar module like [xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html) for json, I'm using the [`jq` cli tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Since a restart in the underlying application is required (which takes some time, since it's an heavy and old java app), I'd like to have a change detection so the restart is only applied when needed.

The return code with the `-e` parameter doesn't change, so my idea was to fetch the hash of the file before `jq` runs and compare it with the hash after that. Fetching the hash could be done with the `stat` module:

```
- set_fact: 
    common_properties_file: "{{ resources_dir }}/commonProperties.json"

- name: Get hash of {{ common_properties_file }}
  stat: path={{ common_properties_file }}
  register: coomon_properties_check

- name: Hash before modification
  debug:
    var: coomon_properties_check.stat.checksum
```

But during testing I found out that the hash even changes when just printing the file without any modification. A diff shows that the entire file got modified by different indention:

```
# jq '.' resources/commonProperties.json > resources/commonProperties.json_jq
# colordiff resources/commonProperties.json resources/commonProperties.json_jq
2,14c2,10
<     "name": "Notification mail customization",
<     "type": "com.ibm.connections.notification.mail",
<     "payload": {
<         "platformName": "HCL Connections",
<         "photoType":"url",
<         "style": {
<             "bodyBackgroundColor": "#eeeeee",
<             "sidebarBackgroundColor": "#3d6cf0",
<             "messageBackgroundColor": "#ffffff"
<         },
<         "activityDateFormat": "dd MMM",
<         "activityMax" : "25",
<         "subjectAppNameAppend" : "tail"
---
>   "name": "Notification mail customization",
>   "type": "com.ibm.connections.notification.mail",
>   "payload": {
>     "platformName": "HCL Connections",
>     "photoType": "url",
>     "style": {
>       "bodyBackgroundColor": "#eeeeee",
>       "sidebarBackgroundColor": "#3d6cf0",
>       "messageBackgroundColor": "#ffffff"
16c12,16
<     "path": "notify"
---
>     "activityDateFormat": "dd MMM",
>     "activityMax": "25",
>     "subjectAppNameAppend": "tail"
>   },
>   "path": "notify"
```

I also tried `jq --tab` without success. The only way I see is to write a small Ansible module that parse the json to an array, check if the modifications need to be applied and set the changed state so that I can use them to decide if we need a restart.

Is there a native way without having to write an Ansible module for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether the new file is JSON-equal to the original file using jq's `==` operator.  One way to do this without generating any output on stdout would be to use jq's built-in `halt_error/1`.  There are many possibilities, but here is a simple stand-alone illustration:

```
echo '{"a": 0}' | jq --argfile f1 <(echo {}) '
   if . == $f1 then empty else null|halt_error(99) end'
```

To avoid calling jq twice, an alternative would be to use jq BOTH to write out the possibly-altered file AND to set the return code as appropriate, along the lines suggested by the above example using `halt_error`.

Comment: That's a good idea. `p="HCL Connections" jq 'if .payload.platformName == env.p then . else .payload.platformName = env.p | halt_error(99) end' resources/commonProperties.json > /tmp/out.json 2>&1` works but with one side effect: When I set `p="HCL Connections1"` (= modification needed), the output json `/tmp/out.json` is minified: `{"name":"Notification mail customization","type": ...` That's hard to read for debugging purpose, is there a way to get it pretty? Without modification (the `.` part of the if) it's prettified, but it seems that `halt_error` stops before prettifying is done

Comment: Regarding to the pretty output, this works: `p="HCL Connections1" jq 'if .payload.platformName == env.p then . else .payload.platformName = env.p, (empty|halt_error(99)) end' resources/commonProperties.json` But `echo $?` gave me `0`, even when the command replaced `"platformName": "HCL Connections` by `"platformName": "HCL Connections1` - the RC worked in the previous command `p="HCL Connections" jq 'if .payload.platformName == env.p then . else .payload.platformName = env.p | halt_error(99) end'` which gave me RC 99 in `$?`

Comment: Whoops, I meant `if .payload.platformName == env.p then . else .payload.platformName = env.p , ( null|halt_error(99)) end`

Comment: This works and also makes the redirect of stderr to stdout unnecessary cause the json got printed formatted to stdout instead of unformatted to stderr. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @peak I found a solution:

```
jq --arg platform "MyPlatformName" 'if .payload.platformName == $platform then . else .payload.platformName = $platform, (null|halt_error(99)) end' resources/commonProperties.json > /tmp/out.json
```

This would result in returncode 99 if the file was edited

```
# echo $?
99
```

If we re-run the tool on the modified file, no modification needs to be applied and we got rc = 0

```
# jq --arg platform "MyPlatformName" 'if .payload.platformName == $platform then . else .payload.platformName = $platform, (null|halt_error(99)) end' /tmp/out.json > /tmp/out2.json
# echo $?
0
```